# BeautifulSoup4, get info from data-stat element

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm a high school student organizing an event for some friends. For the event, I need to scrape data of players for a video game called Rainbow 6 Siege.

I need to extract a number from a thing called data-stat in the HTML code. For example, below I'm trying to extract the 1.03 from "RankedKDRatio". How can I cleanly do this? Thanks for taking a look!

```
<div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="RankedKDRatio">
            1.03
```

My current code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


url = "https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/Juke.TMT"

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: ```for ranked_ratio in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'trn-defstat__value'}):
    print(ranked_ratio.text)``` Maybe you are looking for this?

Comment: @AlexDotis Thanks for your response! I tried it and it is definitely something I can work with. Thanks!